# Proving this result for harmonic function for $|z|>R$ which is similar to Integral formula for harmonic functions in the disc $|z|<R$.

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

This question is from Ponnusamy and Silvermann, p. 369, section on harmonic functions, and I don't know how to answer it.

> If $u(z)$ is harmonic for $|z|>R$ and continuous for $|z|\geq R$ , show that for $\phi =R e^{i\phi}$ , $z =r e^{i \theta}$ ($r>R$),
> $$\DeclareMathOperator{\Real}{\operatorname{Re}}
> u(z)= -\frac{1}{2\pi} \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} \Real \left(\frac {\rho +z } { \rho -z}\right) u\big(Re^{i\theta}\big)d\phi
> $$
> Well, result of harmonic principles were proved for disc $|z|\leq R$ and I am not able to use them as motivation in the question.

It's my humble request to you to help me in the question

Comment: there is something wrong here as $u(z)=\log |z|$ is harmonic for $|z| >R-\epsilon$ and the result trivially doesn't hold for it as the integral is obviously constant then

Comment: This question is extremely hard to read. What is $\rho$? What do you mean by $\phi=Re^{i\phi}$? Can you please provide a picture of the relevant portion of the text as well?